# Modal confirm hides original "action" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement a modal window that opens when the user presses one of two buttons in my form. The modal has two buttons, one to confirm and one to cancel.

My problem is that the server does not receive the attributes of the form button they clicked if that form button calls up the modal. For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" name="action" type="submit" value="-1">Delete</button>
```

I need the `value` attribute to be accessible to my server in order to properly process the form (as the other button has another `value` attribute).

Without, the server recieves this when the user presses the button:

```
[('action', u'0'), ('process-csrf_token', u'1399148515.12##374d9bc0ce1d7f3b30b1865ad592d0c43ada0b7b'), ('process-selection', u'1'), ('process-submitted', u'true')]
```

With the modal, the server receives this when the user presses the button and presses the confirm button:

```
[('process-csrf_token', u'1399148054.19##8d8a9913e2a8e6259b477e49c05a3d326fd935be'), ('process-selection', u'1'), ('process-submitted', u'true')]
```

**How can I make the original button's attributes be sent to the server?**

Here's my javascript:

```
$('button.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e){
    console.log("foo")
    var $form=$(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirmDelete').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .one('click', '#confirm', function (e) {
            $form.trigger('submit');
        });
});
```

And here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Parmanently</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure about this ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a hidden input to the form with javascript depending on what button is pressed?

Comment: that's possible... but it seems like a hack. I wish there were another way.